# anchor tag inside a clickable container doesn't work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I want an entire table row to be clickable, so I'm using this:

```
<tr onclick="location='my_link.html'">
    <td>Clickable Row</td>
    <td>Clickable Row</td>
    <td>Clickable Row</td>
</tr>
```

I also want a small icon inside the row to be clickable with a separate action, so I'm using this:

```
<tr onclick="my_link.html">
    <td>Clickable Row</td>
    <td>Clickable Row</td>
    <td>
        <a href="JavaScript:my_function();"><img src="icon.png" /></a>
        Clickable Row
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is working as expected in Safari, but in Chrome, clicking the button activates the onclick for the row, so there's no way to access my_function.

I tried...

- Giving the icon a higher z-index: no effect
- Calling my_function from an onclick on the icon image instead of an `<a>` tag: no effect
- Wrapping the `<tr>` tag in an `<a>` tag instead of using an onclick: then the row was no longer clickable

Do you have another idea about how to make this work?

Comment: see https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: You can't put a URL in `onclick`, it has to be JavaScript code.

Comment: @Barmar Right -- that wasn't the problem but I just updated my question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `onclick` attribute that calls `event.stopPropagation()`.

```js
function click_row() {
  console.log("Row clicked");
}

function click_a(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("Anchor clicked");
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr onclick="click_row()">
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td><a href="#" onclick="click_a(event)">Click</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That worked. Actually I used this since the stopPropagation isn't needed if the function is called from other places: `<a href="JavaScript:my_function();" onclick="event.stopPropagation();">`